# Standard way to manipulate variadic arguments?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

This is a weird question, but is there a standard way to manipulate the contents of a `va_list` before passing it to another function? For instance, suppose I have two functions, `sum` and `vsum`:

```
int vsum(int n, va_list ap) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        total += va_arg(n, int);
    return total;
}

int sum(int n, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, n);
    int total = vsum(n, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return total;
}
```

If I call `sum` as `sum(4, 1, 2, 3, 4)`, I expect to get the result 10. Now let's suppose that instead of calling `vsum` directly, `sum` calls an intermediate function, `vsum_stub` which does the following:

```
int vsum_stub(int n, va_list ap) {
    va_list temp_ap;
    va_copy(temp_ap, ap);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int *arg = &va_arg(ap, int);
        *arg += 2;
    }
    va_end(temp_ap);
    return vsum(n, ap);
}
```

Now when I call `sum(4, 1, 2, 3, 4)`, I should get back the result 20, since `vsum_stub` increments all of the values in the `va_list` by 2. This doesn't compile of course since you can't take the address of the result of `va_arg`. Is there another way to do this though? I'm working in C99.

---

**Background:**

I'm working on a library that does some pointer translation so that data may be stored on the heap in a more efficient format. Programs are compiled with a custom transformation which converts calls to library functions like `printf` to my own stub functions (e.g., `hc_printf`). `hc_printf` needs to translate any pointer arguments (strings intended for `%s`) before passing the arguments to the real `printf` function.

**Edit:** Here's a code example. Let's say we have a string `foo`. `foo` is dynamically allocated with a modified version of `malloc` which returns a fake pointer. The compiler modifies the program so that it can deal with fake pointers. So this works:

```
char *foo = fake_malloc(4);
fake_strcpy(foo, "foo");
```

I want to write a `fake_vprintf` function like this (in pseudocode):

```
int fake_vprintf(const char *format, va_list args) {
    for each pointer argument p in args
        translate p to q, a real pointer to contiguous memory
        replace p with q in args
    }
    return vprintf(format, args);
}
```

The program would call `fake_vprintf` just like the original `vprintf` using the fake pointer. `fake_vprintf` translates the fake pointer to a real pointer that the real `vprintf` can use.

Comment: Shouldn't `int *arg = &va_arg(ap, int);` actually be `int *arg = va_arg(ap, int *);`?

Comment: @dirkgently, no, the actual parameter inside the argument list is an int. My intent in that example was to get a pointer to that int inside the list so I could change its value.

Comment: I'd assumed that the `vsum_stub` takes in a list of `int *`. Anyway do you think the code I posted is of any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha, as I understand, your problem is creating a new `va_list` argument to pass on to the standard `vprintf` functions. Which in turn, will require you to modify each member of the list. However, since there is no element wise fetch/edit/insert operation for such a list you are stuck.

I don't really see any way of doing this. Of course, you can create a `vprintf` apply the transformations *in situ*, one argument at a time. My suggestion will be: Reimplement *all* such standard library functions -- at any rate you are writing wrappers. This involves some work, but you are already doing a part of it with `hc_printf` etc, so why not go the whole distance (and guess what save on a function call!).

Comment: Reimplementing vprintf and friends is probably the most correct solution. I was hoping there was some way to modify values in the va_list with va_arg, but I guess such a thing is not possible. I'll probably have to decide whether it is better to reimplement vprintf and friends or to have some platform-specific solution for each platform.

Answer (score 3):

You probably can't use va_list in a platform-agnostic way.  You'll have to look at how your environment defines a va_list in stdarg.h, and then write your own tools to work with it.

For example, if a va_list is just a (char *), you can do all sorts of things with it.

```
// add 1000 to the integer stored on the stack and advance va_list
*(int *)va_list += 1000;
va_list += sizeof(int);
```

You're telling the compiler that you want it to consider va_list a pointer to an int (via the int * cast), then take the value (*) and add 1000 to it (+= 1000).  Now advance the va_list pointer to the next argument on the stack.

Comment: This is what I'm currently using, so +1 for that. It works for x86-32 in Linux. However, I will eventually need to port this code to ARM and x86-64, and I believe both of those architectures pass arguments in registers, which may make this approach much more complicated.