# How can I call a method from the C API where the number of arguments is known only at runtime?

Tags: python

I'm using the Python C API to call a method. At present I am using [`PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs) to do this. This is a variadic function:

```
PyObject* PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(PyObject *o, PyObject *name, ..., NULL)
```

This is absolutely fine when the number of arguments is known at compile time. However, I have a scenario where the number of arguments is not known until runtime, they are supplied as an array.

In essence my issue is precisely the same as in this question: [How can I pass an array as parameters to a vararg function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705920/passing-an-array-as-parameters-to-a-vararg-function)

The accepted answer there tells me that there is no solution to my problem.

Is there are way around this hurdle. If I cannot solve the problem using `PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs` is there an alternative function in the Python C API that can meet my needs?

For instance, [`PyObject_Call`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Call) accepts parameters as a Python sequence object. Is it possible to use this function, or one with a similar interface?

Comment: Please provide some [MCVE]. Your question is unclear. In what programming language are you coding in?

Comment: I don't think that the programming language is relevant.  After all, this is an API and therefore available to pretty much any programming language.

Comment: Each programming language *implementation* has its own [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) so what programming language *implementation* you are using is *extremely* relevant. [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) has not the same one as C (that is GCC on my Linux, which follows the Linux ABI)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't agree. I am looking for functions in the Python C API that avoid the need for varidiac argument passing. They exist for other function call like operations. I can call any function in the Python C API.

Comment: Your question is then unclear. I voted to close it.

Comment: If you vote to close then, which is your right, I guess you will delete your answer also. After all, closing says that you feel a question can't or shouldn't be answered.

Comment: No, I often answer to unclear questions, ask the OP to improve them, and improve my answer accordingly to his improvements. I claim that the programming languages (& implementations, or ABIs) of both the calling function and the called function are extremely relevant. The fact that you code in Delphi is *very* important and should be mentioned in your question

Comment: So, assuming that I can call all functions of the Python C API (I can), which ones should I use? I'm looking for expertise in the Python C API. I would like to know which functions in the Python C API to get around this hurdle, if there are indeed any. You appreciate that APIs are language neutral?

Comment: You can use any function documented in [Embedding and extending Python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) if you are coding in C some call (usage) of Python functions or coding in Python some call to C functions. But that chapter don't mention Delphi (and for good reasons).

Comment: Right, so which ones do I use for this problem?

Comment: I dont understand your actual problem. Smells a lot like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Please provide some [MCVE]

Comment: No, I don't think you do understand my problem.

Comment: Then provide some [MCVE] or show some *concrete* code with the actual call

Comment: The problem is at your end. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if I am completey wrong, but AFAICT it should be possible to

- create a tuple with the required number of arguments
- pass this tuple to https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallObject or https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Call (this decision depending on the need for kwargs).

Comment: What do I pass as the `callable_object` parameter? I suppose I'm wondering how to get `self` into the method.

Comment: OK, I see, I can just use `PyObject_GetAttrString` passing the object ref and the method name, and it's all good. I guess what comes back from that is bound. So the answer was in my question after all!

Answer (score 0):

A possible way might be to use [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/), perhaps thru the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) Python library.  It knows your [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) (so is partly coded in assembler, for many popular implementations) and enables you to call an arbitrary function of arbitrary signature and arbitrary arity.

Notice that there is [no purely standard way of doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14705987/841108) (without using some external library à la `libffi`...) in portable and standard [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) (check by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).

BTW, `libffi` can be used from any C program. And `ctypes` can be used from any Python program.

The Python [*Embedding and extending Python*](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) chapter explains how to call Python from C, or C from Python.

Comment: This is certainly a possibility. I was wondering, as in the final paragraphs of the question, whether or not there is an alternative way to call a method using the Python C API.

Comment: I don't understand your "Python C API" expression. Are you coding in C (then use `libffi`) or in Python (then use `ctypes`)?

Comment: The Python C API is documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html  It's how you embed Python, or write extension modules. I'm actually coding in Delphi so `libffi` isn't trivially available.

Comment: That should go into your question!

Comment: I've edited the question to bring out what I am looking for more clearly, I hope. I don't think the language is particularly relevant.